# How prove this $\sum_{i=n+2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}>\frac{2n+5}{2(n+2)^2}$

Tags: inequality

let $n$ be postive integer,show that
$$\sum_{i=n+2}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^2}>\dfrac{2n+5}{2(n+2)^2}\tag{1}$$

I know
$$\sum_{i=n+2}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^2}>\int_{n+2}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2}dx=\dfrac{1}{n+2}$$
But $$\dfrac{1}{n+2}-\dfrac{2n+5}{2(n+2)^2}=-\dfrac{1}{2(n+2)^2}<0$$
then this integral method can't solve (1),so How  to prove it?Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Riemann-Stieltjes integration?

Comment: @JCAA I don't think that is enough

Comment: @JCAA What you say is correct in principle, but even [7 terms is not enough](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%28n%2B2%29%5E2+%2B+1%2F%28n%2B3%29%5E2+%2B+1%2F%28n%2B4%29%5E2++%2B+1%2F%28n%2B5%29%5E2+%2B+1%2F%28n%2B6%29%5E2+%2B+1%2F%28n%2B7%29%5E2+%2B+1%2F%28n%2B8%29+-+%282n%2B5%29%2F%282%28n%2B2%29%5E2%29) and this is prohibitive to check without a computer. Perhaps there is a different approach that is more direct.

Comment: We can show the following identity. $\sum\limits_{k=n+2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^2\binom{k+n+1}{n+1}}.$ Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 6):

There is a rather elegant solution, which uses the convexity of the function. Since $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ is convex, let us consider an area element under the curve versus the area of the trapezoid formed by joining $(n+2,f(n+2))$ and $(n+3,f(n+3)$ by a straight line

$$dA < \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{(n+2)^2} + \frac{1}{(n+3)^2}\right)$$

$$\implies \int_{n+2}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx < \frac{1}{2(n+2)^2} + \sum_{n+3}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{2(n+2)^2} < \sum_{n+2}^\infty\frac{1}{i^2}$$

**EDIT**

Added an illustration of the above just to clarify how I got the inequality

[image]

Answer (score 3):

By using $\frac{1}{q^2} = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x q} x \mathrm{d} x$ for $q > 0$, we have (the summation and the integral are interchangeable by Fubini/Tonelli theorems)
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=n+2}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} &= \sum_{i=n+2}^\infty \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x i} x \mathrm{d} x\\
&=  \int_0^\infty \sum_{i=n+2}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x i} x \mathrm{d} x\\
&= \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x(n+2)} \frac{x}{ 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-x}} \mathrm{d} x\\
&> \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x(n+2)} \left(1 + \frac{x}{2}\right) \mathrm{d} x\\
&= \frac{2n+5}{2(n+2)^2}
\end{align}
where we have used
$$\sum_{i=n+2}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x i} = \mathrm{e}^{-x(n+2)} \frac{1}{ 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-x}}$$
and (see the remark later)
$$\frac{x}{ 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-x}} > 1 + \frac{x}{2}, \ \forall x > 0. \tag{1}$$

*Remark 1*: To prove (1), it suffices to prove that $\mathrm{e}^{-x} > \frac{2-x}{2+x}$  or $-x > \ln \frac{2-x}{2+x}$ for $x \in (0, 2)$.
Let $f(x) = -x - \ln \frac{2-x}{2+x}$. We have $f'(x) = \frac{x^2}{(2-x)(2+x)} > 0$ for $x \in (0, 2)$. Also, $f(0) = 0$. Thus, we have $f(x) > 0$ for $x\in (0, 2)$.

*Remark 2*: $1 + \frac{x}{2}$ is first two terms of the Taylor expansion of $\frac{x}{ 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-x}}$ around $x = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

At least, for "large" values on $n$, we can show it since
$$\sum_{i=n+2}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^2}=\psi ^{(1)}(n+2)$$
So, using the asymptotics of the digamma function and Taylor expansions, we have
$$\sum_{i=n+2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}-\frac{2n+5}{2(n+2)^2}=\frac{1}{6 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$